# tmux - how to use special tokens to indicate particular window and/or pane

Tags: tmux

tmux [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) says

> The following special tokens are available to indicate particular
> windows.  Each has a single-character alternative form.
>
> ```
>  Token              Meaning
>  {start}       ^    The lowest-numbered window
>  {end}         $    The highest-numbered window
>  {last}        !    The last (previously current) window
>  {next}        +    The next window by number
>  {previous}    -    The previous window by number
> ```
>
> The following special tokens are available for the pane index:
>
> ```
>  Token                  Meaning
>  {last}            !    The last (previously active) pane
>  {next}            +    The next pane by number
>  {previous}        -    The previous pane by number
>  ....
> ```

I tried using them like

```
tmux send-keys -t default:!.! "^U"
tmux send-keys -t default:{last}.{last} "^U"
```

It seems like they are not working. What is the correct format to use them?

Comment: can you specify a bit more what exactly is not working correctly for you? As I've put in my answer I can use the commands that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `tmux 3.1b`, with the following session:

```sh
tmux ls
mine: 4 windows (created Thu Jul 30 22:58:44 2020) (attached)
```

being on the last window, with two panes, doing the following

```sh
tmux send-keys -t mine:{end}.! "echo test"
```

and then

```sh
tmux send-keys -t mine:{end}.! "^U"
```

does in fact write "echo test" in the last previously active pane and then clear the line.

EDIT:

note that if you want to use the `!.!` syntax you'll have to escape it:

```sh
tmux send-keys -t 'mine:!.!' "^U
```

as `!.` seems to be interpreted by bash/zsh otherwise

Comment: have you tested `tmux send-keys -t mine:!.! "^U"`

Comment: yes, it works, but I had to escape it and use `tmux send-keys -t 'mine:!.!' "^U"`. I use `zsh`, by the way

Comment: Please update your answer as I could not find any documentation about this escape thing.